# Solve equation numerically containing log

Tags: matlab

I have the following script that defines a function and sets up and equation:

```
H = @(f) sum(log(f));
f = rand(1, 1);

syms a
H(f)-H(f-a)
```

I want to solve `H(f)-H(f-a)=0` for `a`. I tried using fzero in the following manner, `fzero('H(f)-H(f-a)', 0)`, but this doesn't yield me anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

well the clear answer for this would be that a=0. This is of course the obvious answer, and may be why you are not getting "anything useful", especially when only considering one value for `f`.

However, you can actually get useful information when you add more values and use the `solve` function.

```
H = @(f) sum(log(f));
f = rand(5, 1);
syms a
temp = H(f)-H(f-a);
out = double(solve(temp == 0,a));
```

This will output a vector with all values of a that are solutions to your function. Just note that this may not result in the best answers in general, numerical solving of high order functions is rather difficult and unreliable. Because of this, it may take a long time to run as well.